Unit normal vector field along the boundary of a Riemannian hypersurface and the Gram–Schmidt process
I'm studying the proof of the generalized divergence theorem from the brilliant Brian Conrad's notes. Unfortunately, Prof. Brian makes some references to things he said in class when he taught the course, which makes them difficult to read in some places. So I need help.
Let $ (M,g) $ be an oriented Riemannian manifold with boundary. Let $ \vec F $ be a (compactly supported) vector field on $ M $. Let $ \hat N $ be the outward unit normal vector field along $ \partial M $.[1] Let $ \omega_g $ be the Riemannian volume on $ M $ induced by $ g $ and let $ \partial\omega_g $ be the Riemannian volume on $ \partial M $ defined by $ \partial\omega_g = \hat N\mathop{\lrcorner} \omega_g $.
Define two functions respectively on $ M $ and $ \partial M $ in the following way. Let $ \operatorname{div}\vec F $ be the unique smooth function such that
$$
\mathrm d\bigl(\star(\vec F^\flat)\bigr) = \operatorname{div}\vec F\,\omega_g
$$
where $ \vec F^\flat\in \Omega^1(M) $ is the $ 1 $-form corresponding to the vector field $ \vec F $ thanks to metric identification, and $ \star $ is the Hodge-$ \star $ operator. And let
$$
\langle\vec F\rvert_{\partial M},\hat N\rangle
$$
be the function on $ \partial M $ that takes $ p\mapsto \langle\vec F(p)\rvert_{\partial M},\hat N\rangle(p) $, where $ g = \langle{-},{-}\rangle $.
For completeness' sake, the theorems states that
$$
\int_M\operatorname{div}\vec F\,\omega_g = \int_{\partial M}\langle\vec F\rvert_{\partial M},\hat N\rangle\,\partial\omega_g
$$
but this will not be relevant to the question.
At some point during the proof Prof. Conrad more or less takes some $ p\in \partial M $ and some coordinate chart $ \{x^1,\dots,x^n\} $ defined on an open set $ U $ around $ p $ such that $ \partial M\cap U = \{x^n = 0\} $, and applies the Gram–Schmidt process to the induced frame $ \{\partial_1,\dots,\partial_n\} $ on $ U $. The result is an orthonormal frame $ \{e_1,\dots,e_n\} $ such that $ \{e_1\rvert_{\partial M},\dots,e_{n-1}\rvert_{\partial M}\} $ is also orthonormal. At this point the man says

Now recall (by definition!) that the unit normal $ \hat N $ along $ \partial M $ satisfies the property
$$
\langle \hat N,\partial_n\rangle > 0
$$
at each point $ q\in \partial M\cap U $ [and that's ok: $ \hat N(q)\in \mathrm T_q(\partial M)^\perp $ and the metric is positive definite and we picked an orientation]. This crucial positivity property ensures that for $ q\in \partial M\cap U $ the final vector at the end of the Gram-Schmidt process applied to the ordered basis $ \{\partial_\mu(q)\} $ is in fact $ \hat N(q) $! [Simple question: why? He then proceeds.] Make sure you understand this [I do not], as it is the whole reason why the unit normal field $ \hat N $ as we defined it is really relevant to the theorem at hand. [I don't know how they defined it during the lecture, but maybe someone with some expertise might guess the definition].

I highlighted the point with which I have trouble with. I think It's a matter of definitions but some help is definitely appreciated.

In fact, this is the opposite of the usual convention. Since we model boundary points by the upper half-space $\Bbb H^n$, it follows that $-\partial/\partial x^n$ is outward-pointing. Subtracting the projection onto $T_p(\partial M)$ and normalizing gives $\vec N$.
